# (JsonInclude.Include. NON_NULL) only in certain scenarios

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is it possible to use (JsonInclude.Include. NON_NULL) only in certain scenarios? for example
I have an object with 3 fields and if a condition is met then fields 2 & 3 will be null, and I only want to return field 1 which is fine. But if condition is not met, then all fields are to be returned including potential null values. So somewhere outside of the object class itself can (JsonInclude.Include. NON_NULL) be applied to the object for specific scenario?

Comment: you can add a custom Validator for your Json.

Comment: how can it be implemented for this example?

Comment: Sorry you can use a custom annotation for this. Below is a good example for https://www.baeldung.com/java-custom-annotation which can be used for reference